# how to fix aapt2 error in android Studio 4.1.1?

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

few days ago i deleted the whole gradle file and installed it again manually
introduced its path to android studio 4.1.1 and created a project to test

fortunately gradle worked fine but when i tried to run app on emulator a red goddamn error appears that doesn't let me sleep for 3 days

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
   > Could not find aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-linux.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.1-6503028).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/4.1.1-6503028/aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-linux.jar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

i read the documentation and i guess that was outdated or just couldn't solve my problem
cause i declared repository and nothing made a difference.

every solution i found belongs to 2 or 3 years ago and most of em say the same

add `google()` to your `repositories` in `build.gradle`

and they were right

that should made the problem solved but in 3 years ago.

now by default android studio has `google()` in `repositories`
and still i see the goddamn red error on my screen

in error obviously points to missing a file named `aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-linux.jar` and thanks to google ,it gives me the download link
i downloaded the file but i don't know where to put it.

as the error says ,

`Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.`

so anybody knows a path for this file or what ever it is ?!

make an old noob programmer HAPPY ;(

Comment: any updates? I am facing the same problem. Although not in all projects.

Comment: I have the exact same problem! The error says "could not find ..." but when I click on the file link of aapt2 jar, I can download the file. And I don't know where to put the file. Every time I update my Android-studio, I have to stop everything and fix the errors for 2-3 weeks ...

Answer (score 2):

Hi sorry for the late answer ,may be this will use to others
Add Maven to your project build.gradle app it will solve

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. This solved it for me, but I don't know why. Under my Project build.gradle I changed the classpath in my dependencies to a lower version. I had it set as 4.1.1 but changed it to 3.1.4. I then clicked Sync Now.

I still cannot get my emulator to run, but this got rid of the error.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tolls.build.gradle:3.1.4" //was 4.1.1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After many hours messing with Gradle repository config, etc. This solved the problem:

In Android Studio, go to {File} menu > {Invalidate Caches and Restart},

Then Sync your gradle/project.

It seems that some older files/packages are becoming idiotic when you update your IDE.

p.s I also did {Help} > {Check for IDE updates} and there were updates for Emulator and stuff. It still didn't work, until i used the "Invalidate Caches" option.